# VS 2017 - fatal error on sync or pull

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, git-commit

I am trying to sync in VS 2017 incoming and outgoing commits and I'm getting an error:

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
pull --verbose --progress --no-edit --no-stat --recurse-submodules=no origin
```

If I'm trying to pull only, the error is the same.

Have no clue what's this about and how I can overcome it. Don't know much about git.

Comment: please print entire output. Is that the only line that you are getting?

Comment: That's the only thing I'm getting in vs in Syncronization screen

Comment: can you also share output based on my answer below?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I undid the changes to `.gitignore` file which I didn't include in my commits. I think it just clashed when I had changes to pull out from the server.

Either I had to push `.gitignore` or just don't ave any changes to it.

That solved the problem.

Comment: what else were other answers saying and your answer is just too specific which will not be useful for anyone, as the question is too generic. Please avoid such answers.

Comment: Sadly, your answer also has statement like `i think`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have untracked files. You can try *Add*, *Commit* the files, then *Pull* again?

```
$ git add -A
$ git commit -a 'message'
$ git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

run `git status` and see if output presents any file. If there are files in which you have made changes, then you cannot `pull`. You'll have to do one of these

1. commit your changes, and then try to pull
2. discard your changes [`git checkout -f <your_branch_name>`] and then try to pull
3. stash your changes and then try to pull.